# Prove This Function is Finite Almost Everywhere

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

> Let $F$ be a closed subset of $[0,1]$ of positive Lebesgue measure. Let $\delta(x)$ be defined as $\delta(x) = \operatorname{dist}(x, F)$. Consider
>   $$M(x) = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{\delta(y)}{|x -y|^2} \, dy$$
>   Prove that for almost every point $x \in F$, $M(x) < \infty$.

**My thoughts so far are the following**: We wish to show that $M \in L^{1}(F)$, which is more than sufficient to complete the proof. Thus, consider
$$\int_{F} \int_{0}^{1}\frac{\delta(y)}{|x -y|^2} \, dy \,dx$$
From here, I would like to proceed by using Fubini Theorem to switch the order of integration to 
$$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{F} \frac{\delta(y)}{|x -y|^2} \, dx \,dy$$
From here, I am not really sure what to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that
$$
M(x) = \int_{F^c\cap I}\frac{\delta(y)}{|x-y|^2}dy
$$ where $I=[0,1]$. Hence by Tonelli's theorem, we have
$$\begin{eqnarray}
\int_F M(x)dx &=& \int_{F^c\cap I}\delta(y)\left(\int_F\frac{1}{|x-y|^2}dx\right)dy\\
&\le&\int_{F^c\cap I}\delta(y)\left(\int_{|z|\ge \delta(y)}\frac{1}{|z|^2}dz\right)dy\\
&= &\int_{F^c\cap I}\delta(y)\frac{2}{\delta(y)}dy= 2|F^c \cap I| \le 2.
\end{eqnarray}$$

Comment: I think you mean Tonelli as Fubini requires the integrand to be in $L^1$ already.

Comment: @GuachoPerez Thanks for the correction!